# Can't understand the problem in this c++ code

Tags: c++

I have two vectors one called **menlocations**, which stores objects that consist of two double values that represent a coordinate in the x-y plane.

The second vector is called **radiators**, which contains objects that consist of three double values, two of them are plane coordinates and the third is the radius that the radiator can cover in the x-y plane.

Now the objective is to determine the number of men who will need a blanket because none of the radiators are close enough for them to get warm.

What i'am planning to do is iterate over all men and all radiators calculating the distance between each man and each radiator and then counting the number of men who are not close to any radiator so that i know how many blanket i need to bring.

I've tried this code

```
double dist=0;
int blankets=0;

for(double i=0; i<menlocations.size(); i++){
    for(double j=0; j<radiators.size(); j++){
        dist = sqrt( pow((menlocations[i].x - radiators[j].x),2) + pow( (menlocations[i].y - radiators[j].y) ,2) );
        if (dist <= radiators[j].r)
            goto there;

    }
    blankets++;
    there:;
}

cout<<blankets<<endl;
```

and, although it calculates the distances right, it fails to count the number of blankets correctly and i can't seem to put my hands on the mistake here.

thanks in advance...

***note:** i have omitted the declaration of the objects and the vectors since i'am positive the problem isn't residing there.

***note:** If you have a better strategy to tackle such a problem, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `double` types as indexes?

Comment: Floating-point number calculation contain some errors. To reduce effecct of these errors, you should use a small value `EPS` (something like `1e-7`) to compare: `dist < radiators[j].r + EPS` instead of `dist <= radiators[j].r`.

Comment: If only integers will be used in the coordinates, it is a good idea to avoid using floating-point number.

Comment: If you reduce the shown information on the area where you think the error is, then you risk finding out that you could not solve the problem because the error is elsewhere, usually in the code you left out. Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I've tried `integer` types as indexes and I've made all coordinates `integer` numbers as well but I still have the same issue.
@cigien
@MikeCAT

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ No, it won't work because it can cause duplicate counting. You should use found flag and `break;` instead of `goto`.

Comment: In that case, update your question to show the changes.